# Can I set the height of a div based on a percentage-based width?

Tags: css

Let's say I've got a div that has a width of 50% of the body. How do I make its height equal to that value? So that when the browser window is 1000px wide, the div's height and width are both 500px.

Comment: it can't be done in straight css. the js solution is simple though.

Comment: It can actually be done with CSS alone. See Fadi's answer.

Comment: Another approach, which also works for setting the width in terms of the height (unlike the padding approach), can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148012/setting-element-width-based-on-height-via-css)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.  This question specifically asks about basing the square on height, not width - a much different problem.

Comment: **Pure JS approach**: `el=document.getElementById('id_div')`  `el.style.height=el.offsetWidth+"px"` This will give u a perfect square. Make your JS file execute this code when page loads -- `window.onload`

Comment: Assuming 100% of the width of the div in question is the same as 100vw, why not just use vw? Is there a good reason?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This can be done with a CSS hack (see the other answers), but it can also be done very easily with JavaScript.

Set the div's width to (for example) 50%, use JavaScript to check its width, and then set the height accordingly. Here's a code example using jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    var div = $('#dynamicheight');
    var width = div.width();
    
    div.css('height', width);
});
```

```css
#dynamicheight
{
    width: 50%;
    
    /* Just for looks: */
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dynamicheight"></div>
```

If you want the box to scale with the browser window on resize, move the code to a function and call it on the window resize event. Here's a demonstration of that too (view example full screen and resize browser window):

```js
$(window).ready(updateHeight);
$(window).resize(updateHeight);

function updateHeight()
{
    var div = $('#dynamicheight');
    var width = div.width();
    
    div.css('height', width);
}
```

```css
#dynamicheight
{
    width: 50%;
    
    /* Just for looks: */
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dynamicheight"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need javascript for that. You can do as mentioned below:
height: 0px;
width: 40%;
padding-top: 40%;

Comment: As mentioned above using JavaScript is totally unnecessary and presents problems such as FOUC or worse, disabled JS (nothing will happen). Go with the CSS method.

Comment: @Billy: "totally unnecessary"? You're forgetting that the CSS method below has some tight restrictions. The Javascript method will work in all scenarios where Javascript is enabled.

Comment: @Hubro "tight restrictions"?

Comment: @Billy: At first glance, the div appears to need a set width and absolutely positioned content. Also, taking a look at the comments, the results appear to vary between browsers

Comment: The OP specifically said he wants a div with a set width to have the height reflect that.. The most upvoted answer (which still works without box-sizing: border-box) only uses standard CSS and will work everywhere. No comment on the FF issue though.. :P

Answer (score 154):

This can actually be done with only CSS, but the content inside the div must be absolutely positioned.  The key is to use padding as a percentage and the `box-sizing: border-box` CSS attribute:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some unnecessary content.</p>
</div>
```

Adjust percentages to your liking. Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fadi/QzVF9/)**

Comment: I understand that `width: 40%` is 40% of the parent element, but what is the `padding: 40%` in relation to?

Comment: The padding is what gives the box equal width and height.  It 'inflates' the inside of the box with padding.

Comment: Firefox seems to have an issue on that method, but it's simple to fix. If you want a 50% box, you need "padding: 25%;". 25% on each side.

Comment: At least in Chrome, the width value is almost unnecessary. It basically needs to be anything that's not 100% - the actual size of the box is set by the padding. (And Chrome exhibits the same behavior as jurihandl mentioned for Firefox.)

Comment: @BenjaminVisness You're mostly correct in that the width can be any value, but the value can't be left out or the width will default to 100%.

Comment: @Fadi That's why I said it was "almost" unnecessary - the value is irrelevant, but it much be present (and not 100%) in order for this to work.

Comment: @BenjaminVisness ahh I read almost as "at most" :)  Thanks!

Comment: I would say that width must not be more than DOUBLE of padding, as if it was, it would be larger than its padding-computed width. checked in chrome

Comment: I hate how you can do 3D transforms, shadows, rounded corners, etc easily in CSS, but to have a square div requires a hack...

Comment: I vote this as the best answer. I need a 4/3 ratio for photos and wanted a purely CSS solution. Much appreciated.
(So I'll tweak the padding for my use.    padding: 37.5% 50%;)

Comment: @Ryan the `padding: 40%` is in relation to the width of the element (including padding-top and padding-bottom). Definitely surprised me, there's a good explanation on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/1314762).

Comment: the problem is the width percentage set is not what we expect du to padding acting on it. For example, I couldn't use this technique for three inline-block divs with 33% width... As @implum suggested, setting padding-top instead of padding works better.

Comment: Padding should be 40% 0 0 0

Comment: @Jonathan, yes. Try cetering things vertically :p Flex.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy That is actually incorrect. The `padding: 40%` is in relation to the with of the *containing* element, not the element itself. So if the container is `1000px` wide, and `padding-bottom: 40%` is applied to its direct descendant, the calculated value of padding will be `400px` regardless of the width of the descendant.

Answer (score 15):

```
<div><p>some unnecessary content</p></div>

div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

For this to work i think you need to define the padding to ex. top? like this:

```
<div><p>some unnecessary content</p></div>

div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

anyways, thats how i got it to work, since with just padding all arround it would not be a square.

Comment: Thank you ! The above answer did render a square but it was not 40% width of its parent.

Answer (score 10):

I made a CSS approach to this that is sized by the viewport width, but maxes out at 100% of the viewport height. It doesn't require `box-sizing:border-box`. If a pseudo element cannot be used, the pseudo-code's CSS can be applied to a child. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QzVF9/1209/)

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width:100vh;
  max-height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[Support table for viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport%20units)

I wrote about this approach and others in a CSS-Tricks article on [scaling responsive animations](https://css-tricks.com/scaling-responsive-animations/) that you should check out.