# CSS: setting a margin to 10% of the window height

Tags: css

I am trying to set an absolutely positioned element's height as 80% and its top and bottom margins as 10% in order to give the element 80% of window height and leave 10% space above and below it as other element's are to appear there.

But as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qnLC2/ , and as mentioned in W3C CSS Box-model spec,  all the margins' widths are actually set as 10% of window width (not height) (try resizing the output screen and making it wider to see the effect as well) .

W3C CSS Box-model spec:

```
The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's
containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. 
If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is 
undefined in CSS 2.1.
```

I wanted to know if there was any CSS only way to resolve this problem.

The jsfiddle code:
html:

```
 <div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
 min-width:20px;    
 min-height:20px;
 background:blue;
 position:absolute; 
 height:80%;
 width: 80%;
 margin:10%;
}
body{
 background:red;   
}
```

Comment: What browser you're talking about? Your example works fine in Webkit. Falls short in IE and Firefox

Comment: I can confirm it works as it should in Webkit.

Comment: well, it looks like that webkit doesn't comply with w3c standards as well as mozilla does

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem there's any way to do it only with CSS. You will need javascript for it as detailed here:
[Can I set the height of a div based on a percentage-based width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062811/height-div-based-on-percentage-based-width)