# Can I calculate width base on height with calc() function in css?

Tags: css

I would like to calculate height base on width value. For regret it's not possible to do something like: `height: width`, but maybe it's possible with `calc()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062811/can-i-set-the-height-of-a-div-based-on-a-percentage-based-width may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css height same as width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width)