# CSS set height related to the width

Tags: html, css

I'm making a album page with HTML and CSS and I want to set my height of the image to be 9/16 of the width.

HTML code

```
<div class = "col-md-12" id = "album-list">
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div id = "album-card" style = "border: 1px solid grey;">
            <img class = "image_thumbnail" src = "images/sampleImage.jpg" alt = "Thumbnail" />
            <div style = "padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                <p class = "card-text"><strong>TITLE HERE</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- More Columns -->
</div>
```

CSS style

```
.image_thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I saw some posts on stackoverflow with similar questions, and the answer was to use `padding-bottom` to set the height according to the width. However, since I gave border around `#album-card`, `#album-card` gets longer in height than it's supposed to be.

How can I set the heigth 9/16 of the width??

Comment: Should be a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062811/can-i-set-the-height-of-a-div-based-on-a-percentage-based-width

Answer (score 0):

To convert the images:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.image_thumbnail');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].height = images[i].width * 0.5625;
}
```

This will select all the images on the page with the according class and will directly convert the height relative to their width (as: 16 / 9 = 0.5625).

Answer (score 0):

> With the help `calc()` in css3 you can calculate width.

```
.image_thumbnail {
    width: calc((100%*9)/16);
}
```

This is [Referance calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp), This may be helpful for you.

Comment: I know this should work by experience, but still doesn't work.. don't know why

Comment: This is setting the height to 9/16 of the height. @GreenRoof

Comment: @GreenRoof, you can use `calc` with `css()` in jquery, i think this will solve your problem....!