# HTML, background picture height and width not scaling with percentages

Tags: html, css

I'm using Webstorm software with HTML and CSS, no other plugins.
I have a `<section>` element, which is a child of nothing but the `<html>` and  tags. This  is given an ID, in which the CSS designates the following:

```css
#bgIMGHeadShot {
        z-index: -1;
        min-height: 25%;
        width:100%;
        background-image: url("Imgs/HeadShot.jpg");
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<section class = "center" id = "bgIMGHeadShot">
    <div class = "clear trapezoid inBlock">
        <nav class = "nav">
            <button class = "left Navbtn"><a href = "Index.html">Home</a></button>
            <button class = "left Navbtn"><a href = "aboutMe.html">About Me</a></button>
            <div class = "left dropdown">
                <button class = "dropbtn"><a href = "robotics.html">Robotics</a></button>
                <nav class = "dropcontent">
                    <button><a href = "software.html">Software</a></button>
                    <button><a href = "CAD.html">CAD</a></button>
                    <button><a href = "competitons.html">Competitions</a></button>
                    <button><a href = "meetTeam.html">Meet The Team</a></button>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <button class = "left  Navbtn"><a href = "seaCadets.html">Sea Cadets</a></button>
            <button class = "left  Navbtn"><a href = "devBlog.html.html">Development Blog</a></button>
            <button class = "left  Navbtn"><a href = "thx.html">A Thank You</a></button>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

A lot of that HTML isn't needed for this but I'm showing you everything inside the , it's supposed to create a trapezoid over the background image that will have navigation buttons inside of it.

both the height, and width of the picture do not size proportionately to the window. I have tried to use both heights: `min-height`, `width`, `min-width`, and **vh** and **vw** values as well for the image. However, the image does not scale with the window and is not the correct size when first loading either. I have also tried to make this image in HTML, rather than setting it as a CSS background image, yet this does not work either. The only way I can set the size of the image is by using **px** values, but I want the image to scale with the browser window. What's wrong with the **%** or **vh** and **vw** values?

Comment: Is it the width AND height that isn't scaling or just one of them? Also, what tag is the ID under?

Comment: Has nothing to do with WebStorm, kindly post your HTML.

Comment: both height and width do not scale, and HTML has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is because you trying to basically trying to define the height and width as a variable. If you set the width to 100% then the image will take up the full page size, irrelevant of what percentage you set the height.

You're best option might be use JS to set the height as [percentage of width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062811/can-i-set-the-height-of-a-div-based-on-a-percentage-based-width).

If you remove `height` from the below snippet then the image will fill 100% of the page and scale accordingly.

```css
img {
    z-index: -1;
    height:100px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/eWtfMME.png">
```

Comment: I've tried this fix, and it seems that the image still does not scale.

Comment: @Lapras Did you want the image width to be 100% and the image retain its original scale?

Comment: yes, I have edited the images aspect ratio to be what I want, so theres no need to adjust scale.

Comment: @Lapras why don't you set the width as what you want it to be as `%`. The image will retain its aspect ratio when the page is resized.