# set div width as a percentage of height

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I am trying to set the width of the `.full_height_div` element using pure css, based on its height. It has to be width-relative-to-height, and not height-relative-to-width. The reason for this is that the parent container (`.set_rectangle_height`) is already a div with height relative to the page width. Obviously, as the page is resized the `div`s on the page will resize, so i cannot set a fixed width in `px` for the `.full_height_div` child.

So `.rectangle` and `.set_rectangle_height` make up the parent container which has a width as a percentage of the page and a height relative to this width. See [here](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio) for an explanation for this method.

But the problem is that then I want to place a div inside the parent with `height: 100%` and width relative to this height. The aim is then that I will be able to alter the browser window size and everything will keep its aspect ratio.

[here is my failed attempt:](http://jsfiddle.net/HSvW4/1/)

```
.rectangle
{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;/*the outermost div is always a % of the page
width, even while resizing*/
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
.set_rectangle_height
{
    padding-bottom: 30%;/*this sets the height of the outermost div
to a ratio of 1:3*/
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.full_height_div/*this is the div that i want to have a width relative
to its height*/
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;/*i will delete this once .square_set_width is working*/
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
.square_set_width
{                   
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%; /*i want to use something like this line to set
the width of this div to be equal to .full_height_div's height - ie a 1:1 aspect
ratio, but padding-left does not work :( */
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

   <div class='rectangle'>
      <div class='set_rectangle_height'>
         <div class='full_height_div'>
            <div class='square_set_width'></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

So, this is what the above incorrect markup looks like:

[image: incorrect layout]

And this is what i want it to look like:

[image: correct layout]

I know I could find the blue square percentage height in javascript, then set the width to be equal to this height, but it would be really handy if there is a pure css fix for what I am trying to do. I will be using this structure a lot and I don't really want to go writing code to resize all the divs on my page.

Comment: yes. now please remove your downvote

Comment: Let me fiddle that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/HSvW4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Element Width Based on Height Via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148012/setting-element-width-based-on-height-via-css/14911949)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript for that. If I understood you, you want a perfect blue square. Use

```
var height = $('.square_set_width').height();
$('.square_set_width').css('width',height);
```

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8kxu/

Edit: instead of doing `padding-bottom: 30%` do `height: 70%` instead. Here is another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8kxu/1/

Edit #2: Sorry, but you cant use css to do this. Its not powerful enough

Comment: but what if the rectangle must scale with the page width? i will update my example code as this may confuse people...

Comment: what do you mean "the rectangle must scale with the page width"?

Comment: so why dont you just change the height of the rectangle?

Comment: i will update the code in the question in 5 minutes to give you a better example of what i mean...

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you correctly

you can do

```
#divID {
 width: 75%;
 margin-left: auto; // this is used to center the container
 margin-right: auto;// this as well
}
```

Comment: i don't think you have understood. imagine a square inside a horizontal rectangle as per my code in the example.