# Div HEIGHT same as width to make a circle

Tags: html, css

I have an horizontal rectangle div container (**parent**)
[image]

with another smaller one inside (**child**).

[image]

I want to make the smaller one (**child**) look like a circle and the height should always be the same as the parent div for all resolutions.

I found a lot of solutions showing how to make a **1:1 proportional div** (for instance, [this example!](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html))  but all of them were based on the width of the div and not the **height**. This means that i need to know the width to apply the solutions but in my case, i can't do that
, since I know the height (100% of the height of the parent) but I don't know the width.

Ive tried to adapt the solution but I was not successful.

Any idea how i can make a 1:1 div knowing the height of the div ?

Thanks !

Comment: here you go - http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: Give your css html you tried thus far.

Answer (score 0):

One slick trick is to use a 1:1 image as a spreader:

```
.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.inner img {
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You could use a plain-color image with a tiny file size, or an SVG image. **[More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148012/setting-element-width-based-on-height-via-css)**.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dn8ek8pr/)**

If you need content to overlay the circle, **[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dn8ek8pr/1/)**.

Comment: I think this is wrong. The height should be dynamic. Not in your case.

Comment: The question is about the circle, not the parent. It accommodates any parent height.

Comment: IF the height is not dynamic (which I don't thik is the case) than the demo is quite fine. I'd just add a `vertical-align` to the inner one, in order to keep the outer DIV's text at the top: http://jsfiddle.net/dn8ek8pr/2/