# Div aspect ratio and height:100%

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm struggling to apply an aspect ratio to a div that should grow to 100% height of it's parent.

[image]
The map div should grow to the height of the card (with is defined by the amount of text) and also maintain a squared 1:1 ratio.

I saw working solutions if the div is using 100% width (like here: https://tailwindcss.com/course/locking-images-to-a-fixed-aspect-ratio) 
But it's not working when I want to have height:100% and therefore using padding-left/right:100%

This is currently my not working attempt:

```
<div class="row">
    <div
      style="position: relative; height: 100%; padding-left:100%"
    >
      <div
        style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        #map
      ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col pt-2">
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understood well, you want to dynamically change the map box width and height based on the text size. Is so, follow this code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="map">
    <p>Map</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content"> 
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.map {
  background: gray;  
}

.content {
  background: white;
  flex: 1;
}
```

jQuery script:

```
$( window ).on("load resize", function() {  
  var width = $('.map').height();  
  $('.map').width(width);
});
```

Comment: is there an other way than using jquery?

Comment: Yes, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148012/setting-element-width-based-on-height-via-css

Comment: Thx, the proposed solution is using a fixed height (e.g. 50vh) but i want it to be 100% of the parent. so this is not working for me