# css row grid item same width as height

Tags: html, css, grid, aspect-ratio

I have a css column grid.
(the icons div is a child of a div with a dynamic/auto height)

The grid items must be squares.
There are a lot of examples how you can achieve this in a row / horizontal approach
For the column / vertical it doesn't work (I can't get it to work)

```css
.icons {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

.icon-wrapper {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
  // width: 0;
  // padding-right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <div class="icon">icon 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-wrapper">
    <div class="icon">123</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: @Temani Afif Read the question please before you close the question. the duplicate answers are for columns not for rows.

Comment: I added 3 duplicates, all of them cover the all the cases of keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: in two cases you know the width. In my situation is the opposite. I know the height not the width. The last one is jQuery. I do not want to / can't use jQuery for my solution.

I aready tried these solution as I mentioned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911949/8620333 .. consider reading *all* the duplicate, jQuery is only inside the question