# How to have <img> tag with background in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a super image which itself has other images (this is to avoid multiple requests for images).

In the other hand I have Bootstrap.

In order to use responsive images I need to put them in a `<img>` tag, but to avoid multiple requests for different images I need to have them in one super-image, so normally I would use css in divs with background property.

Is it w3c valid to have an `<img>` tag with no `src` at all and having background image?

Thanks!

Comment: "In order to use responsive images I need to put them in a <img> tag" - really?  I'd think using CSS background-images would allow for easier use of things like media queries.

Comment: Well... do you have an example or simply want to tell that you know more than others?

Comment: Do you actually want to learn or simply continue to post questions to ask other people to do things like look at a spec that is readily available on the Internet or could be tested by using any validator.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not valid to omit the `src` in `<img>` tag. And frankly I don't see the point of having that kind of `<img>` tag then.

If you want to use background image, use a `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it w3c valid to have an  tag with no src at all and having background image?

No.

To quote from http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-img-element

"... The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL ..."

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite no src tag at all (and I'll leave the discussion if it's useful to others), but you could technically [give a data uri with a transparent 1x1 image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139830/505649):

```
src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

Even though data URIs were never properly formalized, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) suggests this use case should work across all common browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Look into PictureFill for doing responsive images. Essentially it allows you to setup img tags along with media queries: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill