# How to preload images for simplemodal?

Tags: jquery

It seems that, unless the image it displays is already loaded, simplemodal won't resize to encompass the image. I've tried to preload the image, `setContainerDimensions()` and `update()` but I'm too inexperienced with jQuery to implement these possible fixes correctly. I know [others](http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/resize-simplemodal-td56668.html) have had similar issues  but I'm sure it's nothing wrong with simlemodal, which is great.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Load dialog on click
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        overlayClose:true,
        autoResize:true,
        minHeight:400,
        minWidth: 600, 
    });// end of modal.
    $.modal.setContainerDimensions();//seems to do nothing here :(
    return false;
});// end of basic modal on click.
});// end of jQuery function.
```

Comment: Remove the comma after 'minWdth: 600'

Comment: Thanks Tino. Makes my code tidier but does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the resulting image size is known beforehand, a workaround would be to:

1. Add a temporary `src` to the `img` tag, and set it to `data/image` of a transparent gif. Like this answer suggests [Smallest data URI image possible for a transparent image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018611/smallest-data-uri-image-possible-for-a-transparent-image)
2. Set explicit width-height for the image tag

Result is:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" id="myImg" />
```

This way you get a pre-sized box, and you can later swap the image source to your dynamically loaded image

```
$("#myImg").src("image-url");
```