# trying to fix images not appearing on wordpress site

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, image

In one version of chrome I get this wI get this when I inspect an image

```
<img src="http://esg.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudsonlg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="http://esg.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudsonlg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" class="lazy-loaded">
```

In the newer version, where the image does not load, I get this code

```
<img src="" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="http://esg.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudsonlg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" class="lazy-hidden">
```

any ideas for resolving / correcting that missing image link? Thanks!!

Comment: what you did the code please show the code so we can let you know what is the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading an image using data-src and not just src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533464/loading-an-image-using-data-src-and-not-just-src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.lazy-hidden').each(function(){
      var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
      $(this).attr('src',src);
        
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="http://elizabethstreetgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudson-mirrors-sm-lg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" class="lazy-hidden">
<br />
<img src="" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="http://elizabethstreetgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudson-mirrors-sm-lg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" class="lazy-hidden">


<!-- I had used demo image src as your src is not opening in browser too. -->
```

It would be better if you had posted your code, yet you can use this hack to achieve your requirement.

**EDIT**
Let me tell what I have done here, I took current `data-src` of each image, assigned it a variable, then replace current image `src` to the data-src.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bilal, many thanks for writing. Here is the exact code...

working...
<img src="http://elizabethstreetgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudson-mirrors-sm-lg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="http://elizabethstreetgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudson-mirrors-sm-lg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" class="lazy-loaded">

not working...
<img src="" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="http://elizabethstreetgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/ESG-hudson-mirrors-sm-lg-01-600x548.jpg?x80200" class="lazy-hidden">

Comment: I had used two images, so that you wont have any problem in running this js dynamically or for more than one images.

Comment: hi bilal, many thanks for your answer. if this is happening across the site will I need to make changes for every instance or does the code above cover things globally?

Comment: No, you dont need to do changes for every instance. Just paste this js in footer and make sure all the images have '.lazy-hidden' class added. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153838/discussion-between-bilal-hussain-and-emeka-patrick).