# How to remove a border of background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm using background-image to display images but it put a kind of border around the image and I can't get out it.

How can I do that?

```css
body
{
  background-color: grey;
}
.footer-red-bar
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.footer-red-bar img
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-red-bar">
  <img style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)"/>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Use the `src=""` attribute instead of `background-image`

That's the usual border of the ***Broken-Image*** asset that you get when you don't provide a valid `src=""` attribute and the image cannot be found.

[image]

A **BAD** solution is to use a 1x1 transparent pixel - or equally a [base64 representation of the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018611/smallest-data-uri-image-possible-for-a-transparent-image):

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

than it would look like:

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}

.footer-red-bar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.footer-red-bar img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-red-bar">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" 
       style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)"/>
</div>
```

#### But that's not the way to do it.

`img` elements not only need a valid image source trough the **`src=""`** attribute, but also the `alt=""` attribute - which explains to Search Engine Bots and screen readers the subject of the image. A transparent pixel is clearly not something worth an **Alt**ernative attribute.

#### Therefore

1. use your `<img src="image.jpg" alt="Nice green nature">`
2. or use `<div style="background-image='url(image.jpg)'"></div>`

If you use `<img>` but need a `cover` translation like it's done by `background-size: cover;`...

**use `object-fit: cover;`**

Opera Mini has it, so you can expect soon IE/Edge will ([eventually](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6263790-object-fit-and-object-position)) implement that feature too.

> object-fit/object-position shipped in Microsoft Edge included in Windows Insider Preview build 16215.

Or use Google and [do a research](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3) for neat fallbacks.

Answer (score 7):

Using the content css property worked for me:

css

```
img.my-img {
  content: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <img class="my-img"/>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLu9egrf/)

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. This also worked for me base64 image

`img.my-img { content:url("data:image/webp;base64,UklG...");`

Answer (score 4):

The `img` tag requires a `src` attribute. Load a transparent image as the source, and the border will vanish.

```css
body
{
  background-color: grey;
border: none;
}
.footer-red-bar
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.footer-red-bar img
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-red-bar">
  <img style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)" src="http://antonandirene.com/build/images/about/snow-small.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the `img` to a `div` and add:

```
div.img {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  border:none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8on8uu2/)