# memory leak between page reloads on safari in ios

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, three.js, webgl, mobile-webkit

I have a three.js website which when loaded in mobile safari on iphone takes up ~450mb(I found this through "Instruments" utility in XCode).

Now, when I reload this page, the inspector shows that the memory is now ~550mb. And, the next time I reload the page, it crashes altogether(probably due to [crossing the memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15200855/1273830) of 640mb?)

I've tried:

1. Disabling `renderer.render` calls(three.js sends data from main memory to GPU memory during renderer.render) so nothing is sent to GPU, in this case the memory was ~280mb but still, it was increasing with page reloads.
2. Disabling caching on the main page.
3. Freeing up almost all the resources both in main memory and in GPU memory as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606581/1273830).
4. Set any/all images src to 1px data URL as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993689/1273830).

But, the page still crashes due to increased memory between reloads. So, I am confused as to what keeps the browser from freeing up the memory. Any clues?